# Animated plotly gauge plot with changing colors and text annotation

Tags: r, animation, plotly, pie-chart, r-plotly

I have a gauge plot I want to animate (following [this tutorial](https://plot.ly/r/gauge-charts/)), with the color of the plot changing according to the current value. I also want an annotation* which displays the current value of the gauge (I don't want the standard value displayed in the sector).

For the record, I'm trying to use `plotly` instead of `c3::c3_gauge` because I hope to eventually embed this in a `plotly::subplot()` with other plots that'll animate simultaneously.

I currently have the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

riskToHex <- function(x) {
  x <- colorRamp(rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu")))(x / 100)
  rgb <- paste(x[,1], x[,2], x[,3], sep = ",")
  paste0("rgb(", rgb, ")")
}

dd <- data.frame(values = c(90, 60, 20))

dd <- dd %>%
  mutate(colors = riskToHex(dd$values),
         frame = seq.int(nrow(dd)))
dd <- merge(dd, data.frame(values = 200 - dd$values,
                           colors = "white",
                           frame = dd$frame),
            all = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(frame)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_pie(values = dd$values,
          frame = dd$frame,
          rotation = -90,
          marker = list(colors = dd$colors),
          textinfo = "none",
          title = list(text = "Risk score",
                       font = list(size = 20)),
          hoverinfo = "skip",
          sort = FALSE,
          showlegend = FALSE,
          order = "clockwise",
          hole = 0.6) %>%
  add_markers(x = 0,
             y = c(0, 1),
             color = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)') %>%
  add_text(x = 0,
           y = 0.6,
           yshift = 100,
           text = filter(dd, colors != "white")$values,
           frame = distinct(dd, frame)[[1]],
           showlegend = FALSE,
           textfont = list(size = 20)) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 500) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE,
                 zeroline = FALSE,
                 showticklabels = FALSE
                 ),
    yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE,
                 zeroline = FALSE,
                 showticklabels = FALSE
    )
  )
```

This is rather messy and very hacky. I had to use `add_text()` because I couldn't figure out how to get annotations to work in this case with changing values in each frame (whether through `add_annotations` or `layout(annotations = ...)`). Unfortunately, the `add_text()` forced me to add the `layout` block disabling the axes (which otherwise start to appear). And since the pie chart is seemingly printed on paper space, I also had to add two invisible points so that I could actually position the text (otherwise the axes would always keep the text centered).

Regardless, this successfully generates an animated chart. However, the color only seems to change to the correct value on the following frame (by which time it's too late). I don't believe it's just a processing delay or whatever because accelerating the animation speeds up the color changes as well.

[image]

Interestingly, this only happens due to the `add_text()` block. If I comment that out, the colors on the bar work correctly.

[image]

Is there any explanation and solution to this?

---

* I'm open to other solutions!